# Android Google maps with navigation drawer layout

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

i'm making an android app that implements Google maps V2 maps.

When i implement the include layout tag,
map fragment doesn't register clicks or any type of input from the screen.
but when i remove the include tag, i can move the map around.

I've done goggling around but i couldn't find anything that could help.

i've also tried this thread [Google Maps V2 + Drawer Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896909/google-maps-v2-drawer-layout)
but without success.

Here's my layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drawer layout must be the root element in the layout file, like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- google map -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```