# Google map inside drawer layout fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to show a Google Map inside a drawer `Layout` `Fragment`, I've searched a lot but I couldn't reach to a good solution. The last error that faced me is:

```
MainActivity: Error in creating fragment
```

such that the application opens but with mo map shown.

I have added all permissions to the manifest as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.navigationdrawerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapp1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.mapp1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAan9QKDcqWXNfBeF0vUnoHui0itihkXww"/>

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the MapFragment.java looks like:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(32.333, 36.333) ;
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(32.333, 35.333) ;
    static final LatLng Home = new LatLng(31.333, 35.333) ;
    AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    GoogleMap map;
    MapView mapView; // we should use it when we want a Map inside the fragment
    private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    static  int count=0;
    private HashMap<Integer, Marker> WaypointsMarkers = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();

    Marker mr;
    /*****/

        private Fragment mVisible;
        private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
        private Fragment mFriendsFragment;
        private GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapFragment(){

    }




     @Override
     public void onDestroyView() {

         SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

         if (f != null) {
             try {
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

         super.onDestroyView();
     }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
//      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_flight, container, false);
        /********************/

        /****/
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,false);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();


         mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);

         mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         if(mapView!=null)
         {
             map = mapView.getMap();

             map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

             map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

             map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
         }


         /*****^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^***/
        return rootView;
    }


     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        

            Context ctx=getActivity().getApplicationContext();


            Button bt=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button11);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //  WaypointsMarkers.get(1).remove();

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(WaypointsMarkers.get(1).getPosition())      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



                Fragment_Waypoint_info Fragwpt= new Fragment_Waypoint_info();
                FragmentManager manger = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manger.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.main_layout, Fragwpt, "Fragwpt");

                transaction.commit();




                }
            });



            //Spinner

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 R.array.MapType, R.layout.spinner_item2);
         // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         // Apply the adapter to the spinner
         spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
         /***************************************************************/


        }

     // Convert a view to bitmap
        public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Activity context, View view) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);

            return bitmap;
        }


        private void moveToCurrentLocation(LatLng currentLocation)
        {   



            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,20));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
            // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17), 3000, null);


        }


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String MapType1=    (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            if  (position==0)//(MapType1 == "MAP_TYPE_HYBRID")
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            else if (position==1)//(MapType1 == "MAP_TYPE_NONE")
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            else if (position==2)//(MapType1 == "MAP_TYPE_NORMAL")
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            else if (position==3)//(MapType1 == "MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE")
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            else if (position==4)//(MapType1 == "MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN")
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


}// end of MapFragment
```

and the layout.xml is:

```
<fragment 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

I have made the following modifications:
1. add some lines to main activity "activity_main.xml"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

2. modify the main activity "MainActvity.java"

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements{

   private GoogleMap mMap;
   private SupportMapFragment fragment;

   private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
   private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
   private ListView mDrawerList;
   private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

   private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

   private CharSequence mTitle;

   private CharSequence mTitle;

   private int batteryLevel = 2;
   private int gpsLevel = 5;
   private int rssiLevel = 2;
   private MenuItem batteryItem;
   private MenuItem gpsItem;
   private MenuItem rssiItem;
   private MenuItem connectItem;
   /****/
   private EditText et;
   private Button b;
   private int level1 = 1;
   private int flag = 0;

   int position = 0;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

       mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

       ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[2];

       drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_flight_grey600_24dp, "Flight Data");
       drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_database, "Settings");

       DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);

       mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

       mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
               this,                  
               mDrawerLayout,         
               R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
               R.string.drawer_open,  
               R.string.drawer_close 
               ) {

           public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
               super.onDrawerClosed(view);
           }

           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
           }
       };

       mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

       getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           selectItem(0);
       }
   }

   private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
       if (mMap != null) {
           return;
       }
       mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

       if (mMap == null) {
           return;
       }
       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

               MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                       new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");

               mMap.addMarker(marker);

           }
       });

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       batteryItem = menu.findItem(R.id.battery);
       gpsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.gps);
       rssiItem = menu.findItem(R.id.rssi);
       connectItem = menu.findItem(R.id.connect);

   }

   private void selectItem(int position) {


       Fragment fragment = null;

       switch (position) {
       case 0:
           fragment = new FlightDataFragment();
           break;
       case 1:
           fragment = new SettingsFragment();
           break;

       default:
           break;
       }

       if (fragment != null) {
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

           mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
           mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
           setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
           mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

       } else {

           Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
           }
       }


   }
   ```

the following is the code of "FlightDataFragment.java" which is the first fragment in the drawer layout and where the map should be appeared

```
public class FlightDataFragment extends Fragment{

static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(32.333, 36.333) ;
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(32.333, 35.333) ;
static final LatLng Home = new LatLng(31.333, 35.333) ;
AlertDialog.Builder ad;
GoogleMap map;
MapView mapView; 
private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
static  int count=0;
private HashMap<Integer, Marker> WaypointsMarkers = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();

Marker mr;

    private Fragment mVisible;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private Fragment mFriendsFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SeekBar seekBar2;
    private EditText et
    LinearLayout ArtificialHorizonLayout;
    private static View rootView;


public FlightDataFragment() {
}

@Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       if (rootView != null) {

            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }

           try {
               rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_flight, container, false);
            } catch (InflateException e) {
        }

        ArtificialHorizonLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ArtificialHorizonLayout);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();


         if(mapView!=null)
         {
             map = mapView.getMap();

             map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

             map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

             map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
         }


            if(map!=null)
            {
                Marker kiel= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Aircraft")
                .snippet("Cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airplane)));


                Marker HomeMarker= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(Home)
                .title("Home")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.home_3))

                .alpha((float) .8)
                );

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(KIEL)      
                .zoom(25)                   
                .bearing(90)               
                .tilt(30)                   
                .build();                  
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

            View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
            TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
            numTxt.setText("27");

            Marker newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Description")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MapFragment.createDrawableFromView(getActivity(), marker))));

            map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

                    count++;

                       View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);
                        TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
                        numTxt.setText(String.valueOf(count) );

                        Marker newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(arg0)
                        .title("Title")
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(count))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MapFragment.createDrawableFromView(getActivity(), marker))));

                        String Key1 = newmarker.getSnippet();




                        if (newmarker.getSnippet().equals("1"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Key1, 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mr=newmarker;
                        }

                        if (!WaypointsMarkers.containsKey(count))
                        {
                            WaypointsMarkers.put(count, newmarker);
                        }


                }
            });



            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(arg0.getPosition())      
                    .zoom(30)                   
                    .bearing(90)                
                    .tilt(30)                   
                    .build();                   
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    return false;
                }
            });

            }

        return rootView;
    }


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView compass = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
    ImageView typesOfMaps = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
    ImageView takeOff = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView32);
    ImageView gotoHome = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView42);
    ImageView follow = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView52);
    TextView uav_modes = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_uav_modes2);

    final TextView agl_text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.agl_text);
    seekBar2 = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

    AttitudeIndicator attitudeIndicator = new AttitudeIndicator(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    ArtificialHorizonLayout.addView(attitudeIndicator);

    final HorizontalScrollView scroll = (HorizontalScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scroll12);
    scroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);


     }
```

it gives me error on the following 2 lines in "FlightDataFragment.java":

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();            
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

the error :

> cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

I have tried the solutions on the net with no useful result...any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896909/google-maps-v2-drawer-layout). and make sure the drawer layout must be the root element in the layout file.

Sample code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- google map -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the map is loaded, **but the problem still appears in creating the fragments** such that when I want to open other fragment (option) it pushes the error

Comment: you can find the error snapshot at this link: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=a82704f

Comment: fine, the layouts correspond to the fragment appeared....I have seen them for a moment....the map in the main activity loaded and so appeared to me as no layout loaded

Comment: In your `logcat` shows nothing, it should shows which line encounter the error

Comment: Can you send specific(including line numbers) logcat?

Comment: please see the modifications

Comment: If you can upload your project to github and share me the link, it will be more appreciated, too many code there...